# why do I get the error X is not iterable when setting state with the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate, iterable

I have two buttons that when clicked update the state of an array of objects. videoList is a state of an array of objects and currentVideo is a state for the video the user is currently watching. the buttons set the flag id to true or false in the object of the currentVideo. On the first click everything works as expected however if clicked again i get the error: TypeError: videoList is not iterable. How can i fix this?

```
 const true = () => {
    setVideoList(
      ...videoList,
      (videoList[videoList.indexOf(currentVideo)].flag = true)
    );
    // setCurrentVideo(...currentVideo, (currentVideo.flag = true));
  };

  const false = () => {
    setVideoList(
      ...videoList,
      (videoList[videoList.indexOf(currentVideo)].flag = false)
    );
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={true}>
        True
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={false}>
        False
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not update your state correctly. After spreading, you need to turn it into array again. Another thing, pass a function like this if your next state depends on the old one

```
 setVideoList(
     videoList => [...videoList, (videoList[videoList.indexOf(currentVideo)].flag = true) ]
  );
```